# Destructuring ImmutableJS Map for React Component Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

We have a project using React + Redux + ImmutableJS. One of our engineers recently added a helper method to support destructuring an ImmutableJS Map when passing it to a component as props:

```
export function toObjectShallow(mapping: Map) {
    const result = {};
    mapping.map((value, key) => {
        result[key] = value;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Thus, we can still do the following and avoid being verbose with repeated calls to `Map.get`:

```
<XyzComponent {...toObjectShallow(this.props.xyz)}/>
```

Yes, that's essentially making two shallow copies (our method + destructuring) of the original object. That should be of minimal expense. I'm wondering though, since I don't see this kind of recommendation really anywhere else in the React/Redux/Immutable communities, is there something else I'm missing that would make this unideal?

The passed properties are still the original, immutable props. It's just the containing object is mutated which doesn't matter, because it's not getting passed to the component anyways. So, what gives? This seems like such a simple solution while avoiding `toJS()`. Why isn't it really mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Highly debatable question to me, and some of the reasons you can check here: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/extensible-destructuring-proposal
From my perspective there is no reason to do this, because you can pass map to your smarter components, and still get Immutable benefits, but with your approach you still mutating container. So you can update or reengineer your redux side to get a clean state without need to spread Immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "correct" answer I was looking for was to continue using Immutable JS's `toObject()` which does a shallow conversion of an Immutable Map object to a regular object, thus allowing us to continue using syntactic sugar while keeping the properties immutable and not having to use our own shallow copy.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the advice in the redux docs to use a HOC for all connected components to allow me to interact with plain javascript objects outside of redux.  So my selectors and reducers still use ImmutableJS objects, but the rest of the code uses plain javascript objects:

https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html#use-a-higher-order-component-to-convert-your-smart-components-immutablejs-props-to-your-dumb-components-javascript-props

edit- not sure if this is the toJS you are mentioning above, I had assumed you meant ImmutableJS.toJS.

as far as preferences, using an HOC you only need to do it once per component, as opposed to each time you use a component in your method.

Comment: Actually @James asking about why this destructuring Immutable is not a widespread paradigm, but props spread without Immutable is.

Comment: Isn't the difference that you only do it once on a connected component, vs. every single component you pass props to *from* a connected component?

Comment: No, i think that you only do transition to non-immutable props once, every other time you pass props you will pass a Imm.js object. For example a list of users container will get a map with userid:info, then UserCard would get a map of user props, etc, etc till the last avatar will get non-immutable Map.get('avatar_url') for example

Comment: connected component contains 4 other components, you call the method 4 times. <XyzComponent {...toObjectShallow(this.props.xyz)}/> <ABCComponent {...toObjectShallow(this.props.abc)}/>

Comment: I'm mostly just asking what is the "best practice" here? What we're doing works, but it smells. I find it hard to believe there isn't a suggested approach for passing Immutable objects as props to a component (without the verbosity of a bunch of `Map.get()` calls.

Comment: the link is the redux suggested solution to the problem.  you basically keep the immutable stuff in the store, and convert everything to plain javascript  when reading from the store.

Comment: I use the same approach as @brub, it's cleaner to just use plain objects within your react-native components and let your selectors do the conversion.

Comment: @CarlosC from Avvenu?